# PHP Firebase help - Set up JWT

Tags: php, firebase, server, firebase-authentication

On my server I am running a few PHP files that read my Firebase Realtime Database. According to [Firebase's documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) I need to set up custom token to get my [Firebase PHP Client](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php) running. The Firebase document says I need to return this;

```
  return JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "RS256");
```

How exactly do I reference the JWT class? I downloaded a JWT library but I am not sure how to implement this into my project. Any help would be great, I am mainly a mobile developer and have little experience with PHP.

Comment: are you using composer?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`firebase/php-jwt`](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library uses [Composer](https://getcomposer.org). Composer is a dependency manager for PHP similar to Maven in Java if you come from Android development background. You would need to know how to import classes in PHP using require/include functions of PHP. You would need some experience with php to use composer.

In order to use [`firebase/php-jwt`](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library without composer you could use the following sample code: (I downloaded the library inside `jwt` folder)

```
require_once 'jwt/src/BeforeValidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/ExpiredException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/JWT.php';


use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$key = "example_key";
$token = array(
   "iss" => "http://example.org",
   "aud" => "http://example.com",
   "iat" => 1356999524,
   "nbf" => 1357000000
);

/**
 * IMPORTANT:
 * You must specify supported algorithms for your application. See
 * https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-40
 * for a list of spec-compliant algorithms.
*/
$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

print_r($decoded);

/*
 NOTE: This will now be an object instead of an associative array. To get
 an associative array, you will need to cast it as such:
*/

$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;

/**
* You can add a leeway to account for when there is a clock skew times   between
* the signing and verifying servers. It is recommended that this leeway should
* not be bigger than a few minutes.
*
* Source: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#nbfDef
*/
   JWT::$leeway = 60; // $leeway in seconds
   $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**firebase/php-jwt**

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/firebase-php-jwt-angular-rest-api-authentication-using-json-web-token-with-guards-example-tutorial-part-2/)** with [Angular App](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-json-web-token-authentication-tutorial-using-angular2-jwt/)

```
<?php

 // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }


require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT; 
define('SECRET_KEY','Super-Secret-Key');  // secret key can be a random string and keep in secret from anyone
define('ALGORITHM','HS256');   // Algorithm used to sign the token



$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);


$action = $request->action;


// Login section
if ($action == 'login') {

    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password; 

        //A dummy credential match.. you should have some SQl queries to match from databases
        if($email == "freaky@jolly.com" && $password == "12345678")
        {
            $iat = time(); // time of token issued at
            $nbf = $iat + 10; //not before in seconds
            $exp = $iat + 60; // expire time of token in seconds

            $token = array(
                "iss" => "http://example.org",
                "aud" => "http://example.com",
                "iat" => $iat,
                "nbf" => $nbf,
                "exp" => $exp,
                "data" => array(
                        "id" => 11,
                        "email" => $email
                )
            );

            http_response_code(200);

            $jwt = JWT::encode($token, SECRET_KEY);


            $data_insert=array(
                'access_token' => $jwt,                                 
                'id'   => '007',
                'name' => 'Jolly',
                'time' => time(),
                'username' => 'FreakyJolly', 
                'email' => 'contact@freakyjolly.com', 
                'status' => "success",
                'message' => "Successfully Logged In"
            );


        }else{
            $data_insert=array(
                "data" => "0",
                "status" => "invalid",
                "message" => "Invalid Request"
            );  
        }   

}
// Get Dashboard stuff
else if($action == 'stuff'){

    $authHeader = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
    $temp_header = explode(" ", $authHeader);
    $jwt = $temp_header[1];

    try {
        JWT::$leeway = 10;
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, SECRET_KEY, array(ALGORITHM));

        // Access is granted. Add code of the operation here 

        $data_from_server = '{"Coords":[{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27770755361785","Longitude":"-9.011979642121824","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:09 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"}]}';


        $data_insert=array(
            "data" => json_decode($data_from_server),
            "status" => "success",
            "message" => "Request authorized"
        );  

    }catch (Exception $e){

        http_response_code(401);

        $data_insert=array(
            //"data" => $data_from_server,
            "jwt" => $jwt,
            "status" => "error",
            "message" => $e->getMessage()
        );

    }   
}

echo json_encode($data_insert);
?>
```