# Integrating Firebase php-jwt with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication

I have tried to get the [Firebase library](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to work on my codeigniter setup (2.2.0). I have done the composer install, etc. I have tried to then call it from a third_party folder and call it in my model like this

```
function get_new_token(){
 require_once __DIR__.'/../third_party/firebase/jwt/vendor/autoload.php';
 use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
```

However I get the error

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in
```

After much googling, an article suggested to swap the `use` for `require`.

This now gives me this error

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Undefined constant 'Firebase\JWT\JWT'
```

After more searching, I got this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475720/php-firebase-help-set-up-jwt/39477444#39477444) to try, but that doesn't work either.

Now I am stuck and I cannot get it to work and I can't understand why. Can somebody please help as I just want to make a simple firebase token.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try moving the `require_once` and `use` statements out of your function

Comment: Tried that but get this error now. <b>Fatal error</b>:  Undefined constant 'Firebase\JWT\JWT' in

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Hi there, I have got to this point now where it works. If I put the firebase/php-jwt as is into a folder with an index.php file at the root of that folder with this setup  
`<?php
require_once 'jwt/src/BeforeValidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/ExpiredException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/JWT.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
$vari = ['iss' => $email];
$token = JWT::encode($vari, '123', 'RS256');
print_r($token);`
It works, but of course I want the src folders in the third_party folder and the function in a model.

Comment: I know it's been a bit too late to comment but shouldn't you add require and use on the very top of the file like outside class declaration in between `defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');` and `class MyClass extends CI_Controller
`